# Using Regex to add spaces after punctuation but ignore instances of U.S

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using

`(/(?<=[.,])(?=[^\s])/mg,' ')`

to add spaces after . and , that are not followed by spaces. I want to ignore instances of the word U.S.  Could someone help do this?

Comment: only for the initials `U.S.` or you think there are other similar initials that need special care? like i.e. `i.e.`

Comment: `s.replace(/(\bU\.S\.)|(?<=[.,])(?=\S)/g, ($0,$1) => $1 ? $0 : " ")`

Comment: If this is in a browser bear in mind that pos lookbehinds won't work in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex

```
\b(U\.S)\b|([,.])(?=\S)
```

- `\b(U\.S)\b` - Matches `U.S`. Since nothing is mentioned in question so i am considering word boundaries.  (`g1`)
- `([.,])(?=\S)` - Matches `.` or `,` followed by a non space character. (`g2`)

```js
let str = 'ab.c,de'
let str2 = 'U.S xyzU.S U.S xyz.x'

const replacer = (input)=>{
  return input.replace(/\b(U\.S)\b|([,.])(?=\S)/gm, function(match,g1,g2){
  return g1 ? g1 : g2+' '
})
}
console.log(replacer(str))
console.log(replacer(str2))
```